# Ranking system with filters

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I want to make a ranking system for countries, according to population. But what I want is filters for my ranking. The filters are 3 drop down select html tags:

1. all countries (and the list of the countries in a drop down)
2. all regions (generated automatically upon selecting a country), and
3. all times  (2 years , 4 years, 6 years).

The expected population is calculated from a table in the database.

The question is: is it better to calculate the population and store it in a table for each of the filters above? Or, calculate and display them on the spot? I'm confused how to make the system work.

Comment: im facing difficulty of building the ranking database

Comment: Take a step back.  Do you have the core data? What does it look like? Can you already display that in a table?

Comment: yeah i have the core data. i can calculate everything without having any problem. the problem is ranking according to filters, i have some countries and their regions  , and the time duration. the user decides what filter he wants to rank

Comment: you really need to refine question(s) to more specific data. You are asking how to create an application that nobody here really knows how your filters need to work, how dynamic the calculations need to be etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, it's *usually* better to store data in its most basic form, then perform any manipulations when you present it. So in your case, this would be the **"calculate and display them on the spot"** option.

Servers are so fast nowadays that there's rarely a noticeable performance hit from calculating things on the fly, unless the calculations are *very* computationally expensive.

If you store the data in its simplest form - in this case, just the raw population data - you could display the data in new permutations (e.g. new filters) by just changing logic (code), rather than having to change or update (migrate) any of your data.